# "No one let us know" more elegant alternative

Tags: phrase-request, formal-language

I am writing an email and I want to say that some information was not mentioned to us but I want it sound a bit more official and I can't get my head around how to build such phrase/sentence correctly. I was thinking about something like:

*We haven't been made aware of something...*

Which does not sound right. Any suggestions/alternatives please?

Answer (score 3):

*We haven't been made aware of [something]...* is not grammatically incorrect. Maybe the present perfect tense in the negative(*haven't been made aware*) makes it lengthy(and a little odd, if you see it that way).

You could say,

> We received no intimation of the matter.
>
> We weren't informed(or notified) that...
>
> We were unacquainted with the fact that...
>
> We did not receive any information on...

Comment: "unacquainted with the fact" = "didn't know" and is not the same as "was not informed"

Answer (score 1):

A few more alternatives and potential implications:

> The matter was not communicated to us.

This one implies that the fault was on their side for failing to tell you.

> There was no communiqué on the matter.

Less passive-aggressive, but also deflects blame from your self, as it does not mention your "failure" in receiving anything. (Substitute any article of correspondence you wish for "communiqué".)